# Error: "CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid win 32 application" in Clion

Tags: c++, clion

I am new in C++ and I am using CLion as IDE. I am running the typical program to start with:

```
    #include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And I am having the error:

```
Error running Build All: Cannot run program "C:\Users\User\Desktop\C++\main.cpp" (in directory   "C:\Users\User\Desktop\C++"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid win 32 application.
```

Can someone give me some insight to the problem?

Comment: For some reason you're trying to run the source code file, not the executable. I don't know CLion so I can't help how to configure it to run the executable instead.

Comment: 1) you need correct CMakeLists.txt with correct `add_executable` 2) menu: run->edit configurations

Answer (score 0):

This error usually arises when the build files get corrupted or, are not processed properly for any number of reasons.

If you CMakeLists.txt file is correct, delete the folder in cmake-build-debug named as your project name.

If your project name is TEST, cmake-build-debug will have a folder TEST. Delete it and try building and running again.

Answer (score 0):

edit configurations:
"Executable:" has to be set to  , instead of e.g. the path to your main.cpp file.